# MySQL query works in NaviCat but not in SugarCRM

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sugarcrm, navicat

**If any additional information is needed that would help you solve the problem, just let me know.**

I'm running SugarCRM 6.5.20 CE

I have a logic hook that fires for a custom module and when I go to check the log, the query shows an execution time and appears to run just fine, but the database doesn't actually get updated.

I took this same query right out of the sugarcrm.log file and then ran the query in Navicat, and... it updated fine with no problems.

I have already tried

- Some / None / All Backticks around column / table names
- Making sure I wasn't using any reserved words

So at this point I'm wanting to chalk it up to a MySQL version issue possibly. I'm running MySQL version 5.5.49-cll.

```
UPDATE `my_database`.`p_policies_cstm`
LEFT OUTER JOIN r_raises_p_policies_1_c ON p_policies_cstm.id_c = r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1p_policies_idb
LEFT OUTER JOIN r_raises_cstm ON r_raises_cstm.id_c = r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1r_raises_ida
SET factor_c = '1.00', client_ppp_c = '1,529,987.76'
WHERE r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1p_policies_idb = 'e1570120-56e0-5d75-8ab7-574f2ef83a5b'
```

Can someone possibly help think of why it would throw no error but not actually update the database?

Here is also the log file where it fired:

```
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][INFO] Query:UPDATE my_database.p_policies_cstm
            LEFT OUTER JOIN r_raises_p_policies_1_c ON p_policies_cstm.id_c = r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1p_policies_idb
            LEFT OUTER JOIN r_raises_cstm ON r_raises_cstm.id_c = r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1r_raises_ida
            SET factor_c = '1.00', client_ppp_c = '1,529,987.76'
            WHERE r_raises_p_policies_1_c.r_raises_p_policies_1p_policies_idb = 'e1570120-56e0-5d75-8ab7-574f2ef83a5b'
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][INFO] Query Execution Time:0.000363111495972
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][INFO] Get One: |SELECT id_c FROM p_policies_cstm WHERE id_c = 'e1570120-56e0-5d75-8ab7-574f2ef83a5b'|
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][DEBUG] Limit Query:SELECT id_c FROM p_policies_cstm WHERE id_c = 'e1570120-56e0-5d75-8ab7-574f2ef83a5b' Start: 0 count: 1
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][INFO] Query:SELECT id_c FROM p_policies_cstm WHERE id_c = 'e1570120-56e0-5d75-8ab7-574f2ef83a5b' LIMIT 0,1
Wed Jun  1 20:30:06 2016 [26589][1][INFO] Query Execution Time:0.000181913375854
```

Comment: do you execute this query against the same DB?

Comment: Yes, both queries run against the exact same DB

Comment: and for NaviCat (have no idea what is that, sorry) it `UPDATE` if you call it several times? I mean probably you `UPDATE` on first call, and second (called from Sugar) is failed because record is already updated?

Comment: For all intents and purposes, running this query in NaviCat should produce the same thing as If I ran the query in phpMyAdmin. Same thing with SugarCRM. I run the query in PHP, Sugar then runs that query against the database. I ran it from SugarCRM first, it succeeded but didn't update anything. So I copied the query and ran it again in Navicat, then it updated fine. I erased the data and tried again from Sugar, still nothing. But no errors. I run queries all the time from SugarCRM just like this one with absolutely no issue.

Comment: please provide any proof that query executed against same DB. Very often we use some test instances during development and forget to switch between them.

Comment: Trust me, its impossible for it not to have. Sugar wouldn't even be working if it wasn't connected to this database. But for your sake, In the config.php file, it mentions the database name as 'db_user_name' => 'my_database',
and in navicat, that is the exact same db name, with the exact same password. Not to mention that in the same php file where I execute this query, I also do a SELECT statement that brings back information from the same database, so I'm 100% sure this is the same DB

Comment: so before every try you reset or change `factor_c, client_ppp_c` for those records? then you run the query and check in database if it has been changed? if it is the same DB and you see logged execution of query. To me there is only human factor to check. there is no miracles in development, usually it is just something simple we miss. So just log your experiment from the beginning to the end. check mysql values directly in mysql to avoid cached or outdated result to be viewed on every step. How do you check and confirm that query **was not** applied?

Comment: Correct, I reset the values every time to be blank, and I tried running the query in NaviCat, phpMyAdmin, and SugarCRM, and it runs fine all 3 times, but SugarCRM doesn't actually update the database. But it's not throwing any errors either. I have had this issue before now with a different SELECT statement, I was using sub-selects and restructured the statement to not include them and that fixed it. I'm not sure there is any way to re-write this statement though.

Comment: I'll know if the query wasn't applied by the sugarcrm.log file, it will say the words "FAILED QUERY, etc..." and actually display the MySQL error code for me. If it says "Execution Time: 0.000306050", then I know the query was executed by the database. Then I will go NaviCat and scroll through the database to check if the values are actually there, and they aren't. I will go ahead and re-run these steps again just to double check though.

Comment: @Alex, I solved it but I don't know why that worked, I changed the LEFT OUTER JOIN's to INNER JOIN's and it worked... which still makes no sense, why would the INNER JOIN's work in both, but the LEFT OUTER JOIN's wouldn't work ONLY in Sugar...

Comment: As I know `OUTER` part is ignored by mysql server for `LEFT JOIN` and as you said that has no sense. Since I have no access to your DB and Sugar instance I would say you missed something else. but it is difficult to find to me in this "remote" mode :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous answer *appeared* to work, but didn't actually work.

The real solution had to do with using `after_save` logic hook, versus using a `before_save` logic hook.

What I didn't know was that in `before_save` logic hooks, when you fire a SQL query, it was going back over it and firing an Update Statement again, but this time with blank values where I was trying to Update values.

Changing this to an `after_save` immediately solved the issue.